# Pickadate.js setting 'from' 'to' limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, pickadate

Hello guys I am using [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) to set dates for my project and I have run into an issue. I am adding inputs for picking dates in my project dynamically. I have setup `from` `to` limits for them and for the first set inputs they work fine, but for elements that I add dynamically `from` `to` dates don't work. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<h3>Extend <a href="http://http://amsul.github.io/pickadate.js">pickadate v3</a> to get “from” and “to” date functionality.</h3>
<h4>From:</h4>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="input_from" class="input_from">
</fieldset>
<h4>To:</h4>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="input_to" class="input_to">
</fieldset>
<h4>From:</h4>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="input_from" class="input_from">
</fieldset>
<h4>To:</h4>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="input_to" class="input_to">
</fieldset>
```

and JS:

```
$('.input_from').pickadate({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
});

$('.input_to').pickadate({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
});

var from_$input = $('.input_from').pickadate(),
    from_picker = from_$input.pickadate('picker')

var to_$input = $('.input_to').pickadate(),
    to_picker = to_$input.pickadate('picker')


// Check if there’s a “from” or “to” date to start with.
if ( from_picker.get('value') ) {
  to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))
}
if ( to_picker.get('value') ) {
  from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
}

// When something is selected, update the “from” and “to” limits.
from_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))    
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    to_picker.set('min', false)
  }
})

to_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    from_picker.set('max', false)
  }
})
```

I have tried targeting my inputs by using `each()` but it didn't help. Here is codepen where you can see what is happening. Basically I don't how to target limits for `this` set inputs that are clicked. Try using first two inputs and 
 you will see that limits work correctly but they are not getting applied to second set of inputs. 
 https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/KeNRxZ?editors=1010

Comment: Note that "id" attributes must have unique values. It looks like you're re-using the same values over and over again.

Comment: @Pointy I have tried with unique ID-s also. Here is example: http://jsbin.com/nugosuyiqu/2/edit?html,js,output